# Is there a way to dispatch an action from a react functions when it mounts?

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, react-redux

I have a react function that displays a list of things and I use Redux to manage the state of my app. I just wanted to know if there is a way to request things from the server when it mounts.

```
componentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.sendRequest()
}
```

I know how to do it with a React Component, but not with a React Function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? you want to call the redux action using a functional component?

Comment: `useEffect(() => { sendRequest() }, [])`. The first parameter is a function to call every time a value entered in the dependency array (second parameter) changes. With no entry in the dependency array it will only run once on component mount. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: So, I have react function that displays todos, now it takes its state from store and I have hard coded it. I would like it to request todos from db. In the past days I would just create a action and then dispatch it like thiscomponentDidMount = () =>{
     this.props.sendRequest()
} but now I I did it with the function and was not sure how to dispatch an action when the function mounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a react hook called useEffect in order to achieve the componentDidMount behavior:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { sendRequest } from 'your-action-location'
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

const YourComponent = ({ sendRequest }) => {

 useEffect(() => {
  sendRequest()
 },[])


 return (
  <div>
    {/* Your JSX*/}
  </div>
 )
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
   {
    sendRequest
   },
  dispatch
  );
 };

 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

The use effect hook does trigger the sendRequest call only once, when the component mounts, we achieve that by passing an empty array as the second parameter. You can read more on that here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

There are many other ways with hooks to dispatch your action I will suggest to also read this if you want to use other approaches rather than the mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps functions https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#hooks